# How to prove Cayley's theorem using Category Theory

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, category-theory

I am working through the [Steve Awodey's book "**Category Theory**"](https://books.google.ru/books?id=zLs8BAAAQBAJ&dq=steve+awodey&lr=) and there is the **Cayley's theorem** (Every group $G$ is isomorphic to a group of permutations) left for the reader to prove with this sketch of the proof (the page 13):

1. Define the group $\bar G$ of permutations as follows: $\forall g \in G$, there is a permutation $\bar g: G \to G$ defined $\forall h \in G$ by "acting on the left" $$\bar g(h) = g \cdot h$$$\checkmark$I can easily prove that $\bar G$ is indeed a group.
2. Define the homomorphisms: $i: G \to \bar G$ by $i(g) = \bar g$, and $j : \bar G \to G$ by $j(\bar g) = \bar g(1_G)$. $\checkmark$ Check
3. Show that $i \circ j = 1_\bar G$ and $j \circ i = 1_G$

I approach the third point like this: $$\forall g \in G, \space (j \circ i) \space g =\space j\space(i\space g) = j\space \bar g = \bar g\space1_G  = g \circ 1_G = g$$So I get back to $g$, since there is only one identity morphism I can conclude that $j \circ i = 1_G$.

The inverse case ($i \circ j = 1_\bar G$) is proven symmetrically.

What seems to be off for me in this proof is that I deal with elements of the group, which I am not supposed to do. Is my intuition correct? Am I missing something? What is the canonical way to prove this theorem using the category theory?

The author defines a **group** as a **monoid** where every **morphism** is isomorphism, is there a way to use this fact in the proof?

Comment: Yoneda embedding?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoneda_lemma#Relationship_to_Cayley's_theorem

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, thank you for the suggestion, but I am only at the beginning of the book, Yoneda is happening way in the future, the only definitions introduced so far are just the notion of a category, functors, monoids, groups and isomorphisms.

Comment: Well that's the categorical version of Cayley's theorem. Maybe the authors are giving this example now so they can refer to it again when they talk about Yoneda's lemma?

Comment: @TrevorGunn, you might be right. I cannot touch elements of the group, right?

Comment: The proof they sketch involves defining a function  in terms of elements. I don't see how you would avoid touching elements if you're reasoning about those functions.

Comment: Has Awodey introduced natural transformations yet? If so, do you know what the natural transformations between hom functors are? Because then you can "discover" Yoneda easily in this specific context and then get categorical Cayley from this.

Comment: @Matematleta, no definition of natural transformations have been introduced so far. So I don't think Awodey was designing the exercise to be too complicated. My proof might be what the author expected, please leave your answer noting flows in my proof (if any) and also the Yoneda way of proving it so there is an answer. I will think about the group being one element category and if I don't find any better proof I will accept any of the available answers.

Comment: The book does not intend this proof to be done in a category theoretic way - this is clear from the outline they give.  What you're missing is that you think this proof is supposed to use category theory in some essential way and you think you're not supposed to use elements - both of these are off.  The category theoretic proof using Yoneda will presumably be done later in the book (if not, you can find it on Wikipedia or in chapter 2 of Riehl's book).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me sum up the discussion in the comments.

This proof that is sketched isn't particularly categorical but it does relate to the Yoneda embedding $\mathcal{C} \to \mathsf{Set}^{\mathcal C^{\rm op}}$ where we map objects $A$ of $\mathcal{C}$ to their hom-functors $h^{A} : \mathcal{C}^{\rm op} \to \mathsf{Set}$. My guess is that the authors intend to explain the categorical connection later.

In the case were $\mathcal{C}$ is a group with a single object $A$, then $\mathcal{C} = \mathcal{C}^{\rm op}$ and $h^A : \mathcal{C} \to \mathsf{Set}$ takes $A$ to $\operatorname{Hom}(A,A) = G$ and group elements $g : A \to A$ to $\mathsf{Set}$-morphisms $\bar g(h) = g \circ h$. So this gives a map from $G = \operatorname{Hom}(A,A) \to \operatorname{Perm}(G)$.

The subgroup of $\operatorname{Perm}(G)$ which is the image of $\operatorname{Hom}(A,A)$ is the group of natural transformations of $h^A$. A natural transformation of $h^A$ looks like

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
    A @>g>> A\\
    @V h^A V V @VV h^A V\\
    \operatorname{Hom}(A,A) @>>\bar g> \operatorname{Hom}(A,A)
\end{CD}
$$

You can see this all on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoneda_lemma#Relationship_to_Cayley's_theorem). Hopefully the above gives you some categorical context for Cayley's thoerem.

Comment: The statement at the end isn’t entirely correct. $Nat(h_A,h_A)$ is generally a proper subgroup of $Perm(G)$, which is after all a symmetric group! It’s the group of “unnatural” isomorphism of $h_A$.

Comment: @KevinCarlson You're right, let me correct that.

Answer (score 6):

There nothing wrong with looking at elements of the group. If a group is seen as a one-object category, then what would be thought of as elements in traditional abstract algebra now become identified as the morphisms of the category. And one is certainly “allowed” to deal with elements of morphism sets.